# Number of solutions via generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

How to find generating function for number of solutions
$x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ in set of positive integers such that $x_1 \ge x_2 \ge x_3$ and $x_1<x_2+x_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: First rewrite $x_2 = x_3 + d_{2,3}$, with $d_{2,3} \geq 0$ and $x_1 = x_2 + d_{1,2} = x_3 + d_{2,3} + d_{1,2}$ with $d_{1,2} \geq 0$.  In terms of $d_{1,2} \geq 0$, $d_{2,3} \geq 0$, $x_3  \geq 1$, we have arranged for all three variables to be (so far) independent.

Now we need to implement $x_1 < x_2 + x_3$, or, what is the same thing, $x_3 + d_{2,3} + d_{1,2} < x_3 + d_{2,3} + x_3$, which is just $d_{1,2} < x_3$.   Set $x_3 = d_{1,2} + e$ with $e \geq 1$.  Now we have arranged for the problem to be in terms of the independent variables $d_{1,2} \geq 0$, $d_{2,3} \geq 0$, and $e \geq 1$.

Rolling back, we see that \begin{align*}
n &= x_1 + x_2 + x_3  \\
    &= (x_3 + d_{2,3} + d_{1,2}) + (x_3 + d_{2,3}) + x_3  \\
    &= 3 x_3 + 2 d_{2,3} + d_{1,2}  \\
    &= 3(d_{1,2} + e) + 2 d_{2,3} + d_{1,2}  \\
    &= 4d_{1,2} + 2d_{2,3} + 3e  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So the given problem is equivalent to finding a partition of $n$ into zero or more $2$s, one or more $3$s, and zero or more $4$s.

Answer (score 2):

> We   are looking  for a generating function $G(z)$ where the coefficient of $z^n$ gives the wanted number of solutions. We  want to find a proper representation for
>   \begin{align*}
> G(z)=\sum_{{{x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 1}\atop{x_1\geq   x_2\geq    x_3}}\atop{x_1<x_2+x_3}}z^{x_1+x_2+x_3}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In order to simplify $x_1\geq x_2\geq x_3\geq 1$  (and also $x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 1$) we write
\begin{align*}
x_3&=y_3+1\qquad\qquad\  \, y_3\geq 0\\
x_2&=y_2+x_3\qquad\qquad y_2\geq 0\tag{2}\\
x_1&=y_1+x_2\qquad\qquad y_1\geq 0
\end{align*}
We  obtain  from (2):
\begin{align*}
x_1&<x_2+x_3\\
y_1+y_2+y_3+1&<(y_2+y_3+1)+(y_3+1)\\
y_1&<y_3+1\\
\color{blue}{y_1}&\color{blue}{\leq y_3}\tag{3}\\
\\
x_1+x_2+x_3&=(y_1+y_2+y_3+1)+(y_2+y_3+1)+(y_3+1)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=y_1+2y_2+3y_3+3}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

> With the help of (2) and (3) we can write $G(z)$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> G(z)=\sum_{{y_1,y_2,y_3\geq 0}\atop{y_1\leq y_3}}z^{y_1+2y_2+3y_3+3}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

In order to simplify $y_1\leq y_3$ in (5) we write
\begin{align*}
y_3&=t_3+y_1\qquad\quad t_3\geq 0\\
y_2&=t_2\qquad\qquad\quad\, t_2\geq 0\tag{6}\\
y_1&=t_1\qquad\qquad\quad\, t_1\geq 0
\end{align*}
and we obtain from (6)
\begin{align*}
y_1+2y_2+3y_3+3&=t_1+2t_2+3(t_3+t_1)+3\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=4t_1+2t_2+3t_3+3}\tag{7}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (5) - (7) 
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{G(z)}&=\sum_{t_1,t_2,t_3\geq 0}z^{4t_1+2t_2+3t_3+3}\\
> &=z^3\sum_{t_2\geq 0}z^{2t_2}\sum_{t_3\geq 0}z^{3t_3}\sum_{t_1\geq 0}z^{4t_1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{z^3}{(1-z^2)(1-z^3)(1-z^4)}}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Consider the diagram

[image]

where the number of dots in column $1$ is no greater than the number of dots in column $2$, which is no greater than the number of dots in column $3$, which is equal to the number of dots in column $4$ (columns $3$ and $4$ are identical).

The diagram represents a solution to
$$
a\le b\le c\quad\text{and}\quad c\le a+b\quad\text{and}\quad a+b+c=n\tag1
$$
where $a$ is the number of dots in column $2$, $b$ is the number of dots in column $3$, $c$ is the sum of the number of dots in columns $1$ and $4$, and $n$ is the number of dots in all columns. All solutions to $(1)$ can be uniquely represented this way.

We can count the number of solutions to $(1)$ by looking at the diagrams sideways. Each diagram represents a term in the expansion of
$$
\frac1{1-x^2}\frac1{1-x^3}\frac1{1-x^4}\tag2
$$
The diagram above represents the $x^{16}$ term from
$$
\underbrace{\color{#AAA}{\overbrace{\left(1+\color{#000}{x^2}+x^4+x^6+\cdots\right)}^{\large\frac1{1-x^2}}}}_\text{$1$ rows with $2$ dots}
\underbrace{\color{#AAA}{\overbrace{\left(1+x^3+\color{#000}{x^6}+x^9+\cdots\right)}^{\large\frac1{1-x^3}}}}_\text{$2$ rows with $3$ dots}
\underbrace{\color{#AAA}{\overbrace{\left(1+x^4+\color{#000}{x^8}+x^{12}+\cdots\right)}^{\large\frac1{1-x^4}}}}_\text{$2$ rows with $4$ dots}\tag3
$$
The diagram

[image]

represents the $x^{16}$ term from
$$
\underbrace{\color{#AAA}{\overbrace{\left(1+x^2+\color{#000}{x^4}+x^6+\cdots\right)}^{\large\frac1{1-x^2}}}}_\text{$2$ rows with $2$ dots}
\underbrace{\color{#AAA}{\overbrace{\left(\color{#000}{1}+x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots\right)}^{\large\frac1{1-x^3}}}}_\text{$0$ rows with $3$ dots}
\underbrace{\color{#AAA}{\overbrace{\left(1+x^4+x^8+\color{#000}{x^{12}}+\cdots\right)}^{\large\frac1{1-x^4}}}}_\text{$3$ rows with $4$ dots}\tag4
$$
Thus, the number of such diagrams with $n$ dots is
$$
\left[x^n\right]\frac1{1-x^2}\frac1{1-x^3}\frac1{1-x^4}\tag5
$$
That is, the generating function for the number of solutions to $(1)$ is given by $(2)$.

---

Each solution to $(1)$ can be mapped uniquely to a solution of
$$
a\le b\le c\quad\text{and}\quad c\lt a+b\quad\text{and}\quad a+b+c=n+3\tag6
$$
by adding $1$ to $a$, $b$, and $c$. Thus, the number of solutions to $(6)$ is given by $(5)$.
Therefore, the number of solutions to
$$
a\le b\le c\quad\text{and}\quad c\lt a+b\quad\text{and}\quad a+b+c=n\tag7
$$
is
$$
\left[x^{n-3}\right]\frac1{1-x^2}\frac1{1-x^3}\frac1{1-x^4}=\left[x^n\right]\frac{x}{1-x^2}\frac{x}{1-x^3}\frac{x}{1-x^4}\tag8
$$
Thus, the generating function for the number of solutions to $(7)$ is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x^3}{\left(1-x^2\right)\left(1-x^3\right)\left(1-x^4\right)}}\tag9
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is the number of triangles with integer sides and perimeter $n$, also known as [Alcuin's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcuin%27s_sequence).  Its generating function is
$$\frac{x^3}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}.$$